# Disabling a push button after being under pressure for some time?

Tags: arduino-uno

Disabling a push button after being under pressure for some time?

I need to disable a button where the user is pressing for a time it is disabled.

Code:

```
int ledPin = 13; 

int inPin = 7; 

int val = 0; 

void setup() {

pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 

pinMode(inPin, INPUT); 

}

void loop(){

val = digitalRead(inPin);

if (val == HIGH) {

digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

} else {

digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 

}

}
```

Comment: You want to what?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, sorry if the question was misdirected, English is not my main language. What I mean is how to disable a push button after it is pressed for a certain time.

Comment: That's pretty much what you said before.  I don't understand what you want when you talk about "disable a push button". Do you want to have it physically disconnected from your Arduino, or only have the Arduino ignore any state changes from the button?

Answer (score 1):

```
int ledPin = 13; 
int inPin = 7; 
int val = 0;
int oldVal = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT); 
}

void loop(){
  val = digitalRead(inPin);
  if (val == HIGH && oldVal == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    oldVal = HIGH;
  } else if (val == LOW && oldVal == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    oldVal = LOW;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include exactly how this code works and how it's different than the original code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about activating something on a switch push, but only for x seconds. For example, you press a button to sound an alarm, but it stops after 5 seconds.

---

This should do it:

```C++
const byte ledPin = 13; 
const byte inPin = 7; 

const unsigned long MAX_PUSH_TIME = 2000;  // ms
const unsigned long DEBOUNCE_TIME = 20;    // ms
unsigned long whenPushed;

bool switchState; 
bool awaitingRelease;

void setup() 
  {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  }  // end of setup

void switchPushed ()
  {
  // we want them to let go now, ignore it
  if (awaitingRelease) 
    return;

  // is LED already on?
  if (digitalRead (ledPin) == HIGH)
    {
    // held for too long? turn off LED, remember it 
    if (millis () - whenPushed >= MAX_PUSH_TIME)
      {
      awaitingRelease = true;
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
      }  
    return;  // all done
    }

  // turn LED on, remember when    
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
  whenPushed = millis (); 
  delay (DEBOUNCE_TIME);
  }  // end of switchPushed

void switchReleased ()
  {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
  awaitingRelease = false;  // they released it! 
  delay (DEBOUNCE_TIME);
  }  // end of switchReleased

void loop()
  {
  switchState = digitalRead(inPin);
  if (switchState == LOW) 
    switchPushed ();
  else
    switchReleased ();
  }  // end of loop
```

---

**Note:** I used an input pull-up resistor on the switch to avoid having to use extra components. Thus the switch is wired between pin 7 and **ground**. That is why the test for the switch being pressed is for it to be LOW.

---

### Reference

- [Switches tutorial](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches)